# Swing - text input and ouput to text area

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

I want to make simple GUI with Swing, which will have 2 input text fields and a button.

Based on the input the program will fetch `name`/`rol-no`/`age`/`emailid` from table and need to show into a text area below in the same screen. The text area should be scrollable. I want input/output to be in the same screen.  Could some one tell which layout will be ideal for this?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
School(label1):textfield1____
class(label2):textfield2____
SUbmit(Button1)

      name(label2)     roll-no(label3)      age(label4)   email-id(label5) 
row-1  -----
row-2  ----
row-3  ----
row-4  ----
.
.
row-nth ---
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hi
Tried with below code.. but the table positined incorreclty.Please help.
public class test {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(1000, 1000);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setResizable(true);

    final JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("School ");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    pnl.add(lbl, c);

    final JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    tf.setText("");
    pnl.add(tf, c);

    JLabel lb2 = new JLabel("Class");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pnl.add(lb2, c);

    final JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(20);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    tf2.setText("");
    pnl.add(tf2, c);

    final String[] columnNames = { "name", "roll-no", "age", "email-id" };
    Object[][] columnData = new String[2][4];
    columnData[0][0] = "X";
    columnData[0][1] = "1";
    columnData[0][2] = "22";
    columnData[0][3] = "X@XMAIL.COM";
    columnData[1][0] = "Y";
    columnData[1][1] = "2";
    columnData[1][2] = "24";
    columnData[1][3] = "Y@XMAIL.COM";
    JTable table = new JTable(columnData, columnNames);
    table.setBounds(300, 600, 700, 150);

    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    pnl.add(scrollpane);

    f.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, pnl);
    f.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: The bottom area with tabular data (columns & rows) should be a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) in a `JScrollPane` which is added to a layout/constraint that makes it fill the available space.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a `JPanel` using `BorderLayout`, let's call it `content` for now...

I would then create a `JPanel` using a `GridBagLayout` and add your fields to it, lets call this `form` for now...

I would add the `form` to the `content` in the `BorderLayout.NORTH` position.

I would then add a `JTable`, in a `JScrollPane` to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position of `content`

[image]

Start by having a look at...

- [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [How to use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)
- [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)
- [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

For more details...

**Updated with example based on updated question**

You mean something more like...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout30 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout30();
    }

    public TestLayout30() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        public MainPane() {            
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("School ");
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            pnl.add(lbl, c);

            final JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.weightx = 1;
            tf.setText("");
            pnl.add(tf, c);

            JLabel lb2 = new JLabel("Class");
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.weightx = 0;
            pnl.add(lb2, c);

            final JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(20);
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.weightx = 1;
            tf2.setText("");
            pnl.add(tf2, c);

            add(pnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            final String[] columnNames = {"name", "roll-no", "age", "email-id"};
            Object[][] columnData = new String[2][3];
            columnData[0][0] = "X";
            columnData[0][4] = "1";
            columnData[0][5] = "22";
            columnData[0][6] = "X@XMAIL.COM";
            columnData[1][0] = "Y";
            columnData[1][7] = "2";
            columnData[1][8] = "24";
            columnData[1][9] = "Y@XMAIL.COM";
            JTable table = new JTable(columnData, columnNames);
            table.setBounds(300, 600, 700, 150);

            JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
            add(scrollpane);

        }
    }
}
```

Instead of adding all the fields and table to the same panel, use a "master" panel, which uses a `BorderLayout` and add the fields (on a separate panel) to the `NORTH` position and the table to the `CENTER` position.  This is commonly known as compound layouts.  It allows you to devise complex layouts with all the complexity of trying to get it all to fit into a single component...

You also use the `GridBagConstraints` `weightx = 1`, `weighty = 1`, `fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH`, `gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER` to add the table, but that just gets messy...

**Updated with selectable but not editable example**

The `DefaultTableModel` is editable by default.  The only way to change it is to override the `isCellEditable` method and make it `return` `false`

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestLayout30 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout30();
    }

    public TestLayout30() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        public MainPane() {            
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("School ");
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            pnl.add(lbl, c);

            final JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.weightx = 1;
            tf.setText("");
            pnl.add(tf, c);

            JLabel lb2 = new JLabel("Class");
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.weightx = 0;
            pnl.add(lb2, c);

            final JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(20);
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.weightx = 1;
            tf2.setText("");
            pnl.add(tf2, c);

            add(pnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            final String[] columnNames = {"name", "roll-no", "age", "email-id"};
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0) {

                @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    return false;
                }

            };
            Object[][] rowData = new String[2][11];
            rowData[0][0] = "X";
            rowData[0][12] = "1";
            rowData[0][13] = "22";
            rowData[0][14] = "X@XMAIL.COM";
            rowData[1][0] = "Y";
            rowData[1][15] = "2";
            rowData[1][16] = "24";
            rowData[1][17] = "Y@XMAIL.COM";

            for (Object[] row : rowData) {
                model.addRow(row);
            }

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
            add(scrollpane);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, avoid using `setBounds`, it just creates more problems then it solves...

Comment: Hi i tried as you said.. could you please check my code above .. the table  getting positioned incorrectly .

Comment: Add scrollpane to your contentPane's center. 


`JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    //pnl.add(scrollpane);

    f.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, pnl);
    f.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollpane);`

Comment: Thanks ,it worked the table is positioned nicely at center, thats all fine. currently school ,class text fileds are at north-center. I am willing to postion them at top left corner. is that possible.

Comment: Use GridBagConstrains.weightx = 1 for the text fields, you may need to set their anchor to WEST as well

Comment: Thanks alot..  now it got placed as wished.

Comment: the table cells are un editable which is as per requirement, but how to make the cells selectable.

Comment: The should be selected by default?  Can you clarify?

Comment: have set table.setEnabled(false); as dont want the table to be editable. but now unable to select the cells..  want them to be copyable.

Comment: No, the model controls the editability of the table.  So long as `isCellEditable` in the `TableModel` returns `false`, none of the cells will be editable...

Comment: The code is as ... JTable table = new JTable(columnData, columnNames); table.setBounds(300, 600, 700, 150); table.setSelectionMode(0); table.setEnabled(false); the table rows are not selectable.  iwant them to be selectable but un editable.

Comment: You're allowing the `JTable` to create `DefaultTableModel`, by default, this model is editable, instead, you need to create your own instance (or create a custom class which extends from it) and override the `isCellEditable` method to `return` `false`.  Set update

Answer (score 0):

You can use either TableLayout or GridBagLayout. Here are the link for both.

[1. GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) 
[2. TableLayout](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout-141489.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was tired of Java complex layout managers that did not make much sense and moved to:

http://www.miglayout.com/

Easy to install,10 ~ 20 min to get hang of all the basics,it was heaven and made designing for me much easier.
I recommend it over other layout managers.